Is there any way to set an "o" on top of a period?
Is there any way I can type this abbreviation for "Allegro" with LaTex?


If you want automatic size reduction for the o:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\doto{$\stackrel{\text{o}}{\text{.}}$}
\begin{document}
All\doto{} con energico
\end{document}



Thank you, that is the exact solution I want!

You probably want something that adapts to the current font and font size.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\abbr}{m}{%
  \leavevmode% for safety
  \check@mathfonts% to get \sf@size
  \vbox to \fontcharht\font`l{%
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{\fontsize\sf@size{0}\selectfont #1}%
    \copy\z@
    \vss
    \hbox to\wd\z@{\hss.\hss}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{All\abbr{o} con energico}

All\abbr{o} con energico

\noindent
\textsf{All\abbr{o} con energico}

\noindent
\textit{All\abbr{o} con energico}

\noindent
\textit{All\abbr{a} con energica}

\end{document}



I knew Enrico Gregorio would be the perfect person to answer this!


One of these, perhaps.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

All\shortstack[b]{o\\.}


All\shortstack[b]{o\\[-2pt].}

All\shortstack[b]{\small o\\.}

All\shortstack[b]{\small o\\[-1pt].}

\end{document}

